# How can we write winston logs to SQL Server?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, logging, winston

Can you please help me with writing logs to SQL Server Database with WINSTON Package ?

I have tried with below npm package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-sql-transport

But could not able to achieve ?
fetching configuration from another file 
1) config.LOG.IS_DB_LOG 
2) config.LOG.LEVELS.length

```
 getTransports() {
    let trs = [];
        if (config.LOG.IS_DB_LOG && config.LOG.LEVELS.length > 0) {
            trs.push(
             new SQLTransport({
                 level:"error",
                 label:"logger",
                 client: 'mssql',
               connectionString:'mssql://sa:Password@localhost/SQLEXPRESS/',
                 connection: {  
                   user: 'sa',
                   password: 'Password',
                   server: ".\SQLEXPRESS",
                   database: 'EventLogs'
                 },
                 name: 'SQLTransport',
                 pool: {
                   min: 0,
                   max: 10
                 },
                 tableName: 'LOGS'
             })
            );
        }
        return trs;
}
```

//-------Getting tranports and pushing to an array

```
initLogger() {
this.logger = createLogger({
    format: combine(
        label({ label: "logger" }),
        timestamp(),
        myFormat,
        format.json(),
        prettyPrint()
    ),
    transports: this.getTransports(),
    exitOnError: false // do not exit on handled exceptions
});
```

}

I followed the same procedure as mentioned in the document

Comment: Can you post the code which you have tried so far, it will be easy to debug.

Comment: sure @PrabhjotSinghKainth

Answer (score 2):

What I did is created my own SQL Transport with the [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) package. See [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston#adding-custom-transports) link for more info from Winston Transports.

```
const sqlTransport = new SQLLogging();
sqlTransport.on("logged", log => {
  let { message, level, timestamp } = log;
  message = message.toString();
  // vars for DB
  timestamp = moment(timestamp).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    sql.query(
      {
        sql:
          "YOUR QUERY",
        timeout: 9999,
        values: [YOURDATA]
      },
      (error, response) => {
      }
    );
  }
});
```

And in your Logger you have to call your sqlTransport function